# Being able to call a static method as a fallback from an instance in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In python, you can call static/class methods from an instance, for example in the following:

```python
class User:
    # class/static
    NUM_USERS = 0
    MAX_USERS = 10
    @classmethod
    def users_left(cls):
        print ('%d users left' % (cls.MAX_USERS - cls.NUM_USERS))
    # instance
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        User.NUM_USERS += 1
    def greet(self):
        print ('Hello %s' % self.name)

u1 = User('Bob')
u2 = User('Todd')
u2.greet()
u2.users_left() # users_left() is a classmethod
```

However, in javascript it seems you must explicitly call the class, for example:

```js
class User {
    static NUM_USERS = 0;
    static MAX_USERS = 10;
    static users_left() {
        console.log(User.MAX_USERS - User.NUM_USERS);
    }
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        User.NUM_USERS ++;
    }
    greet() {
        console.log('Hello', this.name);
    }
}

u1 = new User('Bob');
u2 = new User('Todd');
u2.greet();

u2.constructor.users_left(); // ok
User.users_left(); // ok
u2.users_left(); // error
```

Is there a way to 'fallback' in javascript like you can in python, or you must explicitly invoke the class?

Comment: It is possible to emulate Python's object model in JS (especially with the help of proxies), but it's absolutely not recommended. Be explicit about whether you mean an instance or a class method if you want to write idiomatic JavaScript.

Comment: @Bergi thank you. What's the most common/idiomatic way to call a class, just using the class name directly, such as `User.users_left()` ?

Comment: It is up to the language design whether calling static method from an instance is allowed or not (even if it is allowed, it is usually not recommended and the compiler/linter will warn you in some language). No big deal as long as the same thing can be done, just different syntax.

Comment: @David542 Yes, just using the class name directly. It's not like you need an instance to dispatch on, do you?